# ArtifactDeployer plugin -remote access denied (Linux to Windows)

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to use the ArtifactDeployer plugin to copy the artifacts from WORKSPACE/jobs/ directory into a remote directory on the windows 7 machine .The Jenkins machine OS is linux

However Jenkins never manages to succeed. Throwing errors like:

```
[ArtifactDeployer] - Starting deployment from the post-action ... [ArtifactDeployer] - [ERROR] - Failed to deploy. Can't create the directory ... Build step [ArtifactDeployer] - Deploy artifacts from workspace to remote directories' changed build result to FAILURE
```

I am not sure how to use the Remote Directory parameter.

Please check the sample code for how I am trying to specify the remote directory

remote Directory - \ip address of that machine\users\public

Is it possible to copy the artifacts which is on linux machine to windows 7 machine?

Please let me know how to specify the remote directory.

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Plugin page doesn't seem to be very helpful when it comes to configuring it. The text seem to hint that you need to have local access (from the node where the job is running) to the (remote) folder you want to deploy too. For a first test, use a local directory (on your Linux box) to see if you get it to work. Second, the correct way to address a windows share is `\\servername\sharename\subdirs`. Remember that you might need to login to the share.

You might need to install samba or cifs to connect to the windows share from your linux system. There is also a setting in Windows that determines whether your windows box will accept connections to aliases. If that is not the case, you need to use the hostname in order to access the share. So IP and any alias for the server will not work then.

```
e.g
  hostname: RTS3524
  alias: JENKINSREPO
  ip: 192.168.15.33
  share: temp
```

For the example above, only `\\RTS3524\temp` will work but `\\192.168.15.33` will not.

Comment: I tried by giving the host name. but its throwing below error        [ArtifactDeployer] - Starting deployment from the post-action ...
[ArtifactDeployer] - [ERROR] - Failed to deploy. Can't create the directory '\\A2ML04967\Users\Public\test'
[ArtifactDeployer] - [ERROR] - Failed to mkdirs: \\A2ML04967\Users\Public\test
Build step '[ArtifactDeployer] - Deploy artifacts from workspace to remote directories' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step '[ArtifactDeployer] - Deploy artifacts from workspace to remote directories' marked build as failure

Comment: mount your windows share into the unix filesystem (samba/cifs). if you can access the folder locally on the linux box. Then you deploy should work.